# In Powershell.. Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit : Access is denied ..How do I get access?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I have very little understanding of PowerShell. I know some cmdlets, but  I am at a loss when it comes to Active Directory. I am using a testcomputer with Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am the administrator.

I used the ISE to test out the following command:

```
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Markedsforing" -Path "DC=testdomene,DC=local" -ProtectedFromAccidentaldeletion $false
```

And it worked. I then tried to add a few commands to see if I could expand on my new knowledge, but he ISE told me there was an error, because there already was an organizational unit called "Markedsforing". I didn't think the ISE would go ahead and make that OU when just running the command before I saved it. but so be it.

Through `Get-OrganizationalUnit -Filter` I get an `ObjectGUID`, which I use in my next command, where I use one of the help commands shown in the examples of `Remove-OrganizationalUnit`. This I do in the PowerShell console.

```
Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 5f528fed-51d3-4c79-088a5d7669a7 -Confirm:$False
```

The answer I get is the following:

```
Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit : Access is denied
```

I can't figure it out in PowerShell ... nor the graphical Interface.

**Question1**: Do I have to use the `-whatif` in the ISE too, so that the ISE doesn't just go ahead and do stuff before I am finished trying to make my commands?

**Question2**: How do I get rid of my OU markedsforing. In the server, I am already administrator.

I will off course omit the `-ProtectedFromAccidentaldeletion $false` next time.
I have also tried with the `-Recursive`

```
Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 5f528fed-51d3-4c79-088a5d7669a7 -Confirm:$False -Recursive
```

I was hoping to get further before using this site. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Raf Yes, I do need to un-protect the OU before deleting it. I thought I made it un-protected when I made my New-ADOrganizationalUnit using the -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false as shown in my first code. I must have made a mistake when applying it. I ended up using the GUI to disable the protection, but I see you used PowerShell. I new there had to be a way to do that, but I never thought of using the "Get" and pipelining it to "Set" before running the "Remove-ADOrganizationUnit". I learn something new every day. Thank you.

Comment: @FrodeF I never thought of putting the $WhatIfPreference = $true in the beginning of the script. The reason for misunderstanding the ISE is most likely that I have used it to try out different cmdlets that retrieves information and never for cmdlets that make changes. Now I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Re Question 1 - what @Frode F. said( further explained here: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_whatif_confirm.htm)

Re Question 2: you need to un-protect the OU before deleting it, in your example:

```powershell
get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity "OU=Markedsforing,DC=testdomene,DC=local" | 
    set-ADOrganizationalUnit –ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
```

then run `Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is PowerShell, whether you use the ISE console or ConsoleHost. If you only want to "simulate" a cmdlet, you can use the `-WhatIf` parameter. If you want to keep WhatIf "on" as default, run

```
$WhatIfPreference = $true
```

at the beginning of your session or script. To overwrite it later when you want to actually run the script, set it to false or add `-WhatIf:$false` to every command that supports `-WhatIf`. You also have the option to use `-Confirm` which ask yes/no before each action(ex. creating a new OU).

As for your `Access Denied`-question. Did your create `Markedsforing` using the `New-ADOrganizationalUnit` or did it already exist? Can you delete the OU using the `dsa.mmc` GUI? PowerShell cmdlets uses the same AD permissions that the GUI uses. So if you're running the PowerShell console as your admin-account, then it seems to be a permission issue in AD.

Answer (score 0):

You can both set the "ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion" to false and delete/remove the organizational unit in one statement (tested and worked using Host version 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2):

First you need to either determine the "distinguishedName" or "objectGUID", since the remove-adorganizationalunit cmdlet only supports those for removing an object.

Running:

```
Get-Help Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit -Full
```

And taking the snippet for "Identity" gives me the following help information:

```
-Identity <ADOrganizationalUnit>
        Specifies the identity of an Active Directory organizational unit object. The parameter accepts the following identity formats. The identifier in parentheses is the LDAP display name 
        for the attribute that contains the identity.

          Distinguished Name 
            Example:  OU=Europe,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com
          GUID (objectGUID) 
            Example: 599c3d2e-f72d-4d20-8a88-030d99495f20 

        The cmdlet searches the default naming context or partition to find the object. If two or more objects are found, the cmdlet returns a non-terminating error. 

        This parameter can also get this object through the pipeline or you can set this parameter to an object instance. 

        This example shows how to set the parameter to a distinguished name.
-Identity  "OU=Europe,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=contoso,DC=com"

        This example shows how to set this parameter to an organizational unit object instance named "OUinstance".
          -Identity   $OUInstance

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    1
        Default value                
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Knowing the "objectGUID", what I prefer to use, I can now delete the OU:

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestOU,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM" -SearchScope OneLevel | Where-Object {$_.objectGUID -eq "c18ff7dc-3177-44eb-896a-5c79cab7ef23"} | Set-ADOrganizationalUnit -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false | Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit
```

Take care in making sure that you are searching in the correct level within the OU structure, this is a common mistake.

Lastly, unfortunately, there is no "PassThru" parameter, so you have to execute a get-adorganizationalUnit command again looking for the OU you just deleted to verify it is gone.

Hope this helps someone!